# case consrtuct of sql in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql

I want to use case construct of SQL:

```
CASE WHEN ans='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

(Where `ans` is a string  declared in ASP.NET) in an insert query like:

```
SqlCommand AnsCmd = new SqlCommand("insert into answers(ans_desc,istrue)values('" + ans1_desc + "',CASE WHEN ans='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)", conn);
```

But it is not working... maybe the syntax is wrong? Please help.

Comment: What is the exception that is thrown?

Comment: actually there is no exception...success is returned but nothing gets inserted in the table

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problem is at the ans variable you use. You should declare it at your query before use it at your CASE statement.

```
DECLARE @ans varchar(1);
SET @ans = 'A';
INSERT INTO answers(ans_desc,istrue)
VALUES('answer desc',CASE WHEN @ans='A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END);
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL variable ans is declared nowhere in your SQL statement.
Where does it come from? Sql or your ASP.NET app?